# How to correctly pass inputs and get outputs from Mex function?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

This is the first time I try to generate a MEX function. I saw some examples of it but I fail when I try to emulate them.
I need to create a MEX function passing through the C code that calls a subroutine where a certain function is evaluated.
The C code from which I start is this:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "source.c"

#define MXCLASS mxSINGLE_CLASS 

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    /* input */
    new_type Index;
    
    /* output */
    INTEGER Flag;
    FLOAT *Result;
    
    Index = (new_type)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,mxINT16_CLASS,mxREAL); 
    plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,MXCLASS,mxREAL); 
    
    Flag = (INTEGER)mxGetScalar(plhs[0]);
    Result = (FLOAT *)mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    
    
    Flag = src_Function(Index, Result);

}
```

where source.c is the C file where the subroutine is defined, src_Function() is the subroutine. The inclusion of src_Function() is correct, because the creation of the MEX function is successful.
new_type is an enumerated type defined in source.c.
The subroutine is defined in source.c as

```
INTEGER src_Function(new_type Index, FLOAT* Result)
{
...
return Flag;
}
```

and Result is computed inside src_Function.
The call to the MEX function is

```
[flag,result] = feval('src_Function_mex',index);
```

where src_Function_mex.mexw64 is the MEX file that has been created by Matlab.
First of all, calling the MEX function, I got that both flag and result were zero. So I did some debug and noticed that I fail in passing the input variable index to the MEX function.
In fact, Index inside the C code is zero and has no sense. This leads to an incorrect evaluation of src_Function and so Flag, which says if the computation failed or not, has a valid value (Flag = -1) which reports some failures in the computation.
Another error occurs when I retrieve flag as output of the MEX function. Because Flag in the C code is -1, but flag in Matlab is zero.
So I believe to be wrong (maybe in the C code) when I collect the input variables and when I try to return the outputs. But I don't know how to correct them.
Any help please?

[Edit]
Thank you very much for your suggestion, Ander! The elements of enum new_type are like:

```
typedef enum new_type
{
    Red;
    Blue;
    Yellow;
} new_type;
```

I tried to edit the MEX function call by passing as input variable the corresponding double

```
[flag,result] = feval('src_Function_mex',double(index));
```

where index is a new_type. Now Index in the C code is right and Flag = 1, which means that the evaluation of src_Function is successful.

[Edit]
To return Flag I used pointers. It works. Thanks

Comment: Can double be casted to your `new_type` ? have you tried making that a double and checking its value ?

Comment: Please update the whole question text, rather than adding a "[edit]" line at the bottom. Reading the question, I have the idea that your main problem is not getting the value of `Flag` back in MATLAB, but apparently you have figured that out. Since you don't have any answers yet, please update your question to reflect your current understanding of the problem. I don't know what problem you still have.

Comment: Note that `#include "source.c"` is very awkward. You should instead include a header file containing the declaration of the function and the types, and separately compile and link the C source file like this: `mex src_Function_mex.c source.c`

Comment: regarding: `#include "math.h"`  `math.h` is a system function so should be included via:  `$include <math.h>` `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input was passed through a cast and output is returned using pointer

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "source.c"

#define MXCLASS mxSINGLE_CLASS 

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    /* input */
    new_type Index;
    
    /* output */
    INTEGER *Flag;
    FLOAT *Result;
    
    Index = (new_type)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,mxINT16_CLASS,mxREAL); 
    plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,MXCLASS,mxREAL); 
    
    Flag = (INTEGER *)mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    Result = (FLOAT *)mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    
    
    *Flag = src_Function(Index, Result);

}
```

And the function call is

```
[flag,result] = feval('src_Function_mex',double(index));
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.